# Two real symmetric matrices are congruent if and only if they have the same rank and signature.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-congruences

So I saw this statement in an exercise :

> Two real $n \times n$ matrices are congruent if and only if they have the same rank and the same signature.

But I was wondering why do we need to state the fact that they must have the same rank. If two real $n \times n$ symmetric matrices have the same signature, doesn't they necessarily have the same rank ? So shouldn't it be :

> Two real $n \times n$ matrices are congruent if and only if they have the same signature.

Comment: Hmm, $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ have the same rank, but have different signatures.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me. I was asking the other way round. I think that if two real $n \times n$ matrices have the same signature, then they have the same rank. But if it is so, why do we need to state it in the exercise ? It is superfluous and yet, I see it formulate like that everywhere.

Comment: Oh I see, my bad.

Comment: Sounds like Sylvester's Law of Inertia.

Comment: It probably is. It still doesn't change my question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct by any standard interpretation of the term "signature". It's difficult to know what the author is going for here.

Answer (score 0):

Some texts define the signature of a bilinear form to be the quantity
$$ \text{no. of positive eigenvalues} - \text{no. of negative eigenvalues}.$$
For instance, see page 372 of Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Algebra*.